# Use JQuery to add a class to an element after doing document.location.href =

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to click on a category, the page will refresh but I would like to keep track of the active category. (only one)

I would like to do something like addClass.

```
<form id="filter_on_cat" action="{$request|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
    <input class="select_default" type="submit" name="2" value="value4">
    <input class="select_3" type="submit" name="0" value="value3">
    <input class="select_2" type="submit" name="1" value="value2">
    <input class="select_1" type="submit" name="3" value="value1">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function search_perso(e){
        // some code                    
        document.location.href = same_page_but_different_content
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.select_default').click(function(){
            search_perso($(this));
            $(this).addClass('active_class');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When you do `document.location.href`, the current page is *unloaded* and the new page is loaded.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how I can manage that. I want to have the new page but I want also to have a new class for the current category.

Comment: `document.location.href = same_page_but_different_content` um.....what?

Comment: You can possibly add the content to the end of the URL, like `http://example.com/youpage#yourcategory`.  Then you can access `#yourcategory` via `document.location.hash`.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know we can do that. 
@j08691 same page but for a different category. So different products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<form id="filter_on_cat" action="{$request|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="1" />Cat 1
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="2" />Cat 2
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="3" />Cat 3
</form>

$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('input[name=category]').change(function () {
        $('form#filter_on_cat').submit();
    });
});
```

Now on the serverside read the post var of "category". From here you can manipulate the button on the continuationpage.

Or you could make links of the categories, and add a parameter to the URL. You can then read the value of the parameter in javascript or serverside code and add an 'active' class.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the state by storing the active element using [HTML5 Local Storage (aka Web Storage)](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).

The example below stores the `name` property of the button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select_default').click(function(){
        localStorage.setItem('activeCategory', this.name); // store locally
        search_perso($(this));
        return false;
    });

    // set the active category by reading from local storage
    var activeCategory = localStorage.getItem('activeCategory');
    if(activeCategory != null){
        $('#filter_on_cat input').filter(function(){
            return this.name == activeCategory;
        }).addClass('active_class');
    }
});
```